# How to work with cross tables in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, relationship

I started using `MySQL` for a few days and I am using it to create a database for my books. Now, since I have a "many to many" relation between author and books and I've added an associative table to fix the relationship. 
1st Table: BOOK 
`book_id` as primary key   
2nd Table: AUTHOR 
`author_id` as pk.  
3rd Table:  BOOK_AUTHOR 
`pk(book_id,author_id)`.
Queries work fine, my problem is that I don't like the way I am filling "book_author", I've used:

`insert into book_author values(X,Y,NULL);`

But in this way, I have to know that 'X' corresponds to "Moby Dick" and 'Y' to "Melville". At the moment, I do it  by asking a specific query manually.

Is there an elegant way to do something like:

```
insert into book_author values("Moby Dick".book_id, "Melville".author_id,NULL);
```

?

Am I missing something?

Comment: You are probably looking for a procedure, so whenever you want to add a book X with an author Y, you will only need to invoke the procedure with the right parameters.

Comment: Are you looking to just insert the data (e.g. a single statement) - or do you want something stored that you can just invoke similar to a method/function?

Comment: You should add you tables fields, otherwise we can not know how to make the insert well (also, why would you put a 'null' value into any row?)

Comment: what's the null value in your insert query? you only show 2 fields in the table, but are inserting 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want an INSERT SELECT, like this:

```
INSERT INTO book_author(book_id,author_id) 
SELECT 
    book.id, 
    author.id 
FROM 
    book 
JOIN 
    author 
WHERE 
    book.name = 'Mody Dick' 
    AND author.name = 'Melville'
```

Answer (score 0):

Little tough to understand the context of what you're trying to achieve without a little more information, but something like the query below will insert based on the criteria given (seeing as though we're inserting into the lookup table)...

```
INSERT INTO `book_author` (`book_id`, `author_id`)
VALUES ((
         SELECT `book_id` 
         FROM `books` 
         WHERE `title` like 'moby dick';
         ),
         (
          SELECT `author_id`
          FROM `authors`
          WHERE `last_name` like 'Melville';
          )
         );
```

*However*, I would assume you would be populating this from some sort of code in an application rather than in SQL (again, since we're populating a lookup table), meaning you'd have an object that you could pass it's parameters negating the necessity of the subqueries. So it would then just be something like:

```
var bookObject = GetSomeBook();
var query = "INSERT INTO `book_author` (`book_id`, `author_id`)" + 
            "VALUES (" + bookObject.BookId + ", " + bookObject.AuthorId + ");";
```

There's also the concept of a Trigger...